# Why doesn't an html table and a textbox line up even though they have the same width in CSS?

Tags: html, css, textbox, css-tables

I have a webpage form with a textbox on one row and a table on the next row.

In my CSS, I have both with the same width:

```
#myTable {
width: 745px;
border: 1px solid;   
border-collapse: collapse;
```

}

```
.fullRowTextBox {
    width: 745px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

but the textbox seems to be a little longer than that table.  Is there any reason why I wouldn't be able to make a textbox and a table the exact same width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Textboxes per default have `padding`. Remove it with

```
.fullRowTextBox {
    padding: 0;
}
```

In that case your table's `width` must compensate the `border`, because tables per default use `box-sizing: border-box`. So set the `width` of the table to the textbox's `width` + `2px`.

Alternatively set the `box-sizing`. With this your `#myTable` and `.fullRowTextBox` can have the same `width` set.

```
.fullRowTextBox {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Attention: This approach may not be [compatible with older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing). And you should add [vendor prefixes](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/css-vendor-prefixes.htm).

Comment: `boxsizing.htc` works fine with IE7 and IE6 if support is needed on these ones (as long as `width` aren't `!important`)